# How to mount the subpath of blockBlob container of storage account on the vm?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, subdirectory, mount

I have a storage account name `storeabc` of blockblob type inside that I have a container named `testcontainer`. I created a folder inside the container named `testfolder`.

I can successfully mount the container(till the container only). using the below command.

`mount -o sec=sys,vers=3,nolock,proto=tcp storeabc.blob.core.windows.net:/storeabc/testcontainer  /nfsdata`

However, I was looking for a way to mount the folder i.e. `testfolder`.

I tried,
`mount -o sec=sys,vers=3,nolock,proto=tcp storeabc.blob.core.windows.net:/storeabc/testcontainer/testfolder  /nfsdata`

which ends up with the error.

```
mount.nfs: mounting storeabc.blob.core.windows.net:/storeabc/testcontainer/testfolder failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory
```

TIA.

Comment: Blob storage is an object store and does not know the concept of folders. They are only virtual parts of the full name of individual objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mount.nfs: mounting storeabc.blob.core.windows.net:/storeabc/testcontainer/testfolder
> failed, reason given by server: No such file or directory

According to this [MS-document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-known-issues#nfs-30-features)    Known issues with Network File System (NFS) 3.0 protocol support for Azure Blob Storage .you can only mount the root directory i.e (Container). Mounting sub directories in azure blob storage not yet supported.

```
 mount -o sec=sys,vers=3,nolock,proto=tcp <storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net:/<storage-account-name>/<container-name>  /nfsdata
```

Please try to type the commands and avoid copy pasting as hidden characters in that command can cause these error.

Reference:
[Mount Azure Blob Storage by using the NFS 3.0 protocol | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/network-file-system-protocol-support-how-to)